# Opencart full category ul li tree

Tags: opencart, opencart2.3, opencart-3

Right now in opencart the system is limited to only showing 2 levels of categories. Does anyone know of a class to get all sub-categories and a full ul li tree?

For example: If you have ever used oscommerce it will show the full tree of sub-cats in the side category menu where as opencart is limited to only two levels.

The default code is like

```
        $categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $children_data = array();

        if ($category['category_id'] == $data['category_id']) {
            $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

            foreach($children as $child) {
                $filter_data = array('filter_category_id' => $child['category_id'], 'filter_sub_category' => true);

                $children_data[] = array(
                    'category_id' => $child['category_id'],
                    'name' => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                    'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])
                );
            }
        }
```

However it only goes two levels, I am looking for all levels to build out an accordion menu.

Further I am not looking for someone to do this, (unless you want), but maybe you can point me in the right direction or to an existing class that will achieve this.

Comment: There is no any class that will retrieve all category levels.
To get category hierarchy, you have to get each level of each category explicitly. Like in default it is fetching one level child-category for each category,so you have to fetch sub-child-category of each child-category.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add each sub-level manually for a 3rd, for a 4th etc. There is no way to just get all of them in one shot.

There was an older stackoverflow thread with a solution on how to add a 3rd level. Perhaps it will work with your version of OC:

[get third level category in opencart 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35803329/get-third-level-category-in-opencart-2)

You basically will need to edit the controller and tpl files for category. If that's too much for you, they sell an extension on their marketplace for it, too.